# JSP, <c:forEach> closes itself to early

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I have jsp page given that is being forwarded a ArrayList were Arrangor is bean like class I made with a constructor and getMethods. But when I try to output them In the jsp page. But firebug finds Instances all of the data being sent. But the <:c forEach> tag seems to be closing itself directly around it. Does anyone have any idea why.

edit: Sorry about the bad sentences. 
edit2 seems a seems the middle sentence got removed

```
<table border="1">
 <c:forEach items="${arrangorer}" var="arr">
 <tr>
   <th>Id</th>
   <th>Namn</th>
   <th>Telefon Nummer</th>
   <th>Email</th>
 </tr>




<tr>
 <td> <c:out value="${arr.id}"></td>
 <td> <c:out value="${arr.name}"></td>
 <td> ${arr.getNumber()}</td>
 <td> ${arr.getEmail()} </td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>

</table>
```

Then I include the abouve jsp fragment in at my index page.

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>


  <div id="include_show">
        <jsp:include page="WEB-INF/show.jsp" />
  </div>
```

I get the following firebug output:

```
<div id="include_show">
  <c:foreach var="arr" items="[src.arrangor.Arrangor@185cfd8,src.arrangor.Arrangor@1073d0src.arrangor.Arrangor@239d58, src.arrangor.Arrangor@2f32d8, src.arrangor.Arrangor@b327ee, src.arrangor.Arrangor@283d9, src.arrangor.Arrangor@11e342e, src.arrangor.Arrangor@1f3f414, src.arrangor.Arrangor@11d5641]"> 
 </c:foreach>
 <table border="1">
 <tbody>
 <tr>
 <th>Id</th>
 <th>Namn</th> 
 <th>Telefon Nummer</th>
 <th>Email</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><c:out value=""></c:out></td>
  <td><c:out value=""> </c:out></td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: please leave a comment when giving downvote.Otherwise how to know to rectify the mistake

Comment: Why is the taglib declaration at the end of the JSP, and not at the beginning, where it should be?

Comment: not so mad about the down vote I had some realy bad grammar I the text. But Does anybody have a guess or thought I should procced I write java fine but "web debuging" is not my strong suite

Comment: @Filip well,listen JB Nizet asking something :0

Comment: yeah I know I had placed the middle sentence wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The taglib declaratiion must be at the top of **every** JSP using the taglib. So it must also be present at the top of `show.jsp`.

Note that there are other errors in your page: unclosed `<c:out>` tags for example.

Comment: Right on the money thanks. Just an informal question can I omit the extra include if i use the .jspf extension instead

Comment: You can only omit it if you statically include it (using `<%@ include file="..." %>`) instead of dynamically include it. And the `.jspf` extension must only be used for statically included JSP fragments (or whatever the new name of JSP fragments is)